# How to get an image's height and set its parent height to auto?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I do the following without jQuery and with pure JavaScript:

What I'm trying to do is to get the height of the image within the figure element and if the image's height is less than 200 pixels than I want its container's (parent's) height to be set to auto.

The jQuery method below is working but I want to do this with JavaScript.

see fiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/6tjn7675/2/)

**HTML**

```
<figure>
<img class="imgH" height="500" width="500" src="/some_img.jpg"/>
</figure>

<figure>
<img class="imgH" height="500" width="500" src="/some_img.jpg"/>
</figure>

<figure>
<img class="imgH" height="500" width="500" src="/some_img.jpg"/>
</figure>

<figure>
<img class="imgH" height="250" width="250" src="/some_img.jpg"/> // This image height is less than 300 pixels.
</figure>

<figure>
<img class="imgH" height="500" width="500" src="/some_img.jpg"/>
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
figure {
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
}
```

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".imgH").each(function(){
    if( $(this).height() < 200 ) {
        $(this).parent().height( "auto" );
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.onload = function () {
    [].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('.imgH'), function(node, i) {
        if (node.clientHeight < 200) {
            node.parentNode.style.height = 'auto';    
        }
    });
}
```

- *document.querySelectorAll('.imgH')* - return nodes which has class
  imgH,
- *node.clientHeight* - get image Height
- *node.parentNode.style.height* - set Height to parent node, in out case parent not is figure

DEmo: http://jsfiddle.net/6tjn7675/4/

Answer (score 1):

so a little bit confusing but are you saying that the jquery version is working but you want it in normal javascript?

If so something like:

```
    if( this.offsetHeight< 200 ) {
        var container = this.parentNode;
        container.style.height = "auto";
    }
```

Is an equivalent statement.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. Okay but how do I get the container for the image and then set the height?

Comment: That's exactly what he is doing. he gets the container `this.parentNode` and then set the height.

Comment: Yeah as Fagner says. I've made it slightly clearer using your container terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-container">

/* image goes here */

</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.image-container').each(function() {
        if ($(this).find('img').length < 300 ) {
            $(this).css({'height' 'auto'});
        }
        });
```

Comment: From condition - The jQuery method below is working but I want to do this with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

From what I can remember:

- You could use `document.querySelector` to get all the image nodes.
- `naturalHeight` and `naturalWidth` properties will get you the computed height and width of the images.
- `parentNode` property of the image node will get you the parent. Apply the required styles and you should be done.

**Edit:**
Just saw Dave Walker's answer. naturalWidth and naturalHeight will give you the original height and width of the image. To get the computed/displayed height and width you must use offsetHeight and offsetWidth.